# Windows file "comment" attribute

Tags: windows, attributes

I would like to change a file's "Comments" attribute ( and all the others too ) from a simple command line.
Can anyone tell me how?

[image: Picture of Windows 7 folder with "Comments" attribute]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Set-ItemProperty cmdlet

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/26/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-work-with-file-attributes/

And

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-6

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: If the linked pages change, my answer will become invalid due to Microsoft changing the syntax, deprecating the cmdlet etc... If anything, the Microsoft link is the source of truth.

Comment: It's more about 404s

Comment: Ok, I'll update it once I'm back in the office

Comment: Thank you for trying, but PowerShell is not a viable solution, as EXE's created are dependant on too many factors ( OS version, Powershell version, .NET version etc... ) and therefore can not be relied upon for any given situation.  Any other suggestions?